# Anylogic Path not found! Agents located in same level and network

Tags: anylogic

Recently I tried replicating @Benjamin Schumann's approach to creating an Agent-Based Anylogic Network since I want to use it for a warehouse simulation project ---> https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/agentify-your-network-pathfinding

The agents are created successfully and the network is visually well represented in Main as per the attached picture. To test the network I have created a transporter fleet agent and a material item agent. When I request a transport agent to move a material item agent from a Rectangular Node to another Rectangular Node I get PathnoFound! error.

image2[image]
image2[image]

I do not understand why I'm getting this error since I have to make sure all agents are located on the same level and are connected to the same network as you can see in the attached picture.
I noticed that the target "rectangular node" has 5 coordinates instead of the standard 3 I do not know why.

In addition, the model works for free space settings with no issues.

any suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The entire purpose of agent-based networks is to bypass material-handling transporters and their black-box path finding. You should not use them or the `moveByTransporter` block.

My approach is to give you more power for agents, not for material-handling objects.

the MH library is great for its purpose but it can be overkill for larger applications. Hence this design which allows you to take full control over everything, be a lot more efficient where needed and add details only when needed.

Hope this makes sense. Use the MH library if you are a beginner or intermediate user, only start with my setup if you know what you are doing and you truly hit the boundaries of default MH / agent network capabilities :)